# how can calculate age years and month and day by dateTimePicker ValueChanged c#

Tags: c#

I use a `DateTimePicker` and I use this code to calculate an age:

```
private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CurrentYear - BirthDate
    int Age = DateTime.Today.Year - dateTimePicker2.Value.Year;

    textBox11.Text = Age.ToString();
}
```

I want to calculate the age by year, month and days when `DateTimePicker`´s value changes.

Comment: Why doesn't the above code work?  Give details.

Comment: work but i want to calculate age year >>days >>month

Comment: Substract datepicker Value's month from Todays month, and same as age ?

Comment: give me value minus in month and days

Comment: You need to go back from current day, otherwise today is 7th March, if you select 9th of March, according to your calculation; it will be -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it calculate only year, below code will give you year, month and days of age.

CODE:

```
private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CurrentYear - BirthDate  
    DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value);
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Today;
    TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
    var totalDays = span.TotalDays;
    var totalYears = Math.Truncate(totalDays / 365);
    var totalMonths = Math.Truncate((totalDays % 365) / 30);
    var remainingDays = Math.Truncate((totalDays % 365) % 30);
    textBox11.Text = string.Format("{0} year(s), {1} month(s) and {2} day(s)", totalYears, totalMonths, remainingDays);
}
```